# TypeError trying to upload a row to DynamoDB; Unsupported type "<class 'numpy.int64'>" for value "0"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Hi I am trying to upload a row I took from a dataframe and upload it to DynamoDB.

I keep getting below error message and it wouldn't get fixed. I tried .astype(int), isinstance and everything I can find and it's still not working. Any thoughts please?

Unsupported type "<class 'numpy.int64'>" for value "0"

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.